# Java структура дженериков

Tags: java, generics

Собственно, можно ли в java прописать что то подобное?

`class MyClass<T extends A && super D>`

Comment: эквивалент - `class MyClass<T extends <A super D>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, максимум, что вы можете сделать - это указать несколько интерфейсов через &:

```
class Container<T extends Serializable & Comparable>
```